# MATLAB - GUI and OPC server

Tags: matlab, user-interface, opc

I want to design a graphical user interface in MATLAB that can read data continuously using the MATLAB's object linking and embedding for process control (OPC) toolbox. How can I implement this?

I have designed the graphical user interface, but I'm not able to read the data into the graphical user interface.

Comment: Do you have the OPC toolbox (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/opc/)? Have you tried the `read` function (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/opc/ug/read.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this submission](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18930) of mine from the MATLAB Central File Exchange. It gives a full example of how to read and write data from an OPC server, and how to create and compile a GUI interface with this functionality as well.

The submission used to have recorded webinar associated with it - unfortunately that seems to have been taken down as it was a bit old. Nevertheless, there's a demonstration script included in the files that walks through the entire process, and I think should give you a good idea of what's going on.

Comment: the file has been removed can you give the correct link here or can you send it to my mail abitha.vs16@gmail.com?                                                                       thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey @sam-roberts can you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803478/dymola-matlab-how-to-write-initialize-tag-for-this-model-realtime-opc

Answer (score 0):

just do this

type `opctool` inside MATLAB

- click create new host
- select Localhost

[image]

- Click add client

[image]

- click add group and add item

[image]

- Now you can see the actual name of variable you want to call
  like `SimControl.Run, SimControl.Stop` , ..etc
- Now you have to code it like this in MATLAB

  ```
           %====================================VARIABLE VALUE===============================
           volume_val=app.VolumeVEditField.Value;
           area_val=app.AreaAEditField.Value;



           %====================================CONNECTION====================================
           global hostInfo ;
           hostInfo = opcserverinfo('localhost');
           global da;
           da = opcda('localhost','Dymosim.OPCServer.1');
           connect(da);
           pause(2);


           %====================================INITIAL VARIABLE=============================
           grp=addgroup(da,'Demo');
           grp2=addgroup(da,'Demo2');
           Initialize=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Initialize'});
           Run=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Run'});
           Status=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Status'});
           Stop=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Stop'});
           Pause=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Pause'});
           %=================================================================================
           write(Initialize,1);

           %you can use write(area,area_val)
  ```
- Then you can use `deploytool` to create app