# OPC Server: Start Stop Pause getData(again use) DYMOLA MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opc, dymola

I am using a Dymola OPC server

DYMOLA HAS these many tags which can be controlled using SimControl.Run, SimControl.Stop ,etc
[image]

here i wrote it in MATLAB

```
hostInfo = opcserverinfo('localhost');
da = opcda('localhost','Dymosim.OPCServer.1');
connect(da);
fprintf("CONNECTED\n");
grp=addgroup(da,'Demo');
itmIDs={'ModelVariables.Tco','ModelVariables.der(Tco)'};
itm=additem(grp,itmIDs);
area=additem(grp,{'ModelVariables.Area'});
set(grp,'UpdateRate',0.2,'RecordsToAcquire',50);
start(grp);
wait(grp);
[logIDs,Tco]=getdata(grp,'double'); // PREVIOUS ONE
Now I want to change/write  value to area so what I did is this
write(area,23);
```

Now I want to Relog or getdata

```
NEWTco=read(itm,'device').Value; //using This I can read one instance
[NewlogIDs,NewTco]=getdata(grp,'double');// GIVES ERR
```

[image]

Comment: Please do say why voted down so I can make it good next time,

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but running Dymosim from OMShell seems odd. And the model has no inputs, so it's not clear if you mean changing parameters using OPC or having actual inputs.

Comment: If I understand you want to change the initial conditions of the model? If so, the easiest would be to add additional parameters and then set them in an initial equation block or using start=

Comment: Thanks a lot @HansOlsson after looking and reading more I get to this point and got stuck here ,

Comment: Seems to be a bit unfortunate timing, but Dymola 2021x discontinued OPC support: https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Dymola-2021x-release-notes.pdf -> page 46, section 3.6.4

Comment: thats a sad moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing this helped me to solve this issue

```
grp2=addgroup(da,'Demo2');
Run=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Run'});
Status=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Status'});
Stop=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Stop'});
Pause=additem(grp2,{'SimControl.Pause'});

RunStatusBefore=read(Run,'device');
StatusBefore=read(Status,'device').Value;
StopStatusBefore=read(Stop,'device');
PauseStatusBefore=read(Pause,'device');

write(Initialize,1);  //INITITALIZE
write(Run,1);  // RUN
write(Stop,1);  // STOP
write(Pause,1);  // PAUSE
```